# Laravel method not allowed exception

Tags: php, laravel

I can't seem to find out why does my submit give me back the `MethodNotAllowedException`. Shortened...here is the form:

```
<form role="form" id="tryitForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      method="POST" action="{{route('user.update', Auth::user()->id)}}">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="Update"/>
```

And I have route set up as:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you could try `method="PUT"`. And are you using a csrf token? Try puting a `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form.

Comment: If I use PUT, then I get redirected as if i called show method. Below the form tag I've set `{!! Form::token() !!}`

Comment: Since you're using a resourceful controller and you're updating, the controller expects a `PUT` or `PATCH` method. What exactly do you mean with "then I get redirected as if I called show method"? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add PUT method into your form.

```
 <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
 <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
```

Comment: Those are input tags...did you mean form or?

Comment: @Norgul He meant inputs. Since HTML forms only support `POST` and `GET` requests, Laravel creates kind of a "faux" `PUT`, `PATCH,` and `DELETE` request by adding a hidden `_method` field. The csrf token is to protect against cross-site request forgeries, and it is required for all `POST` requests.